# ASP Fails with 500 Error

Tags: iis, asp

We have a server setup as an IIS box and have some static pages with a few asp pages that handle the form submissions. The asp is really vbscript that sends a CDO message.

When moving these pages to the new server the form will not submit, it gives a 500 error and the following shows in Event Viewer:

> Error: The Template Persistent Cache initialization failed for Application Pool 'DefaultAppPool' because of the following error: Could not create a Disk Cache Sub-directory for the Application Pool. The data may have additional error codes..

I can't seem to find any info on this anywhere... I was thinking it may have something to do with the fact that we created this server from an image of another server.

Server Info:

> Windows 2008 R2 Datacenter SP1
>
> Hosted on Amazon EC2

***Thanks for your help in advance...***

- Vince

Comment: I've also tried to create another Application Pool to no avail...

Comment: having same problem with an old asp shopping cart, site works for 10-15 minutes then 503. The folders mentioned in the answer not exist on the server

Answer (score 1):

I think this has to do with some permission settings, check if IIS_WPG and NETWORK SERVICE has access to the following folders:

- %systemroot%\Help\IISHelp\Common
- %systemroot%\System32\Inetsrv\ASP Compiled Templates*
- %systemroot%\IIS Temporary Compressed Files

Comment: None of those folders exist